# How do i define a variable conditionally?

Tags: vb.net, class, variables

I have a class set up like the sample below I want to define the variable (var1) based on some info that is passed into the class when it is instantiated. How do I do that?

```
Public Class myClass

  Private var1 as someClass

  Public Sub New(which_type as string)

     if which_type = "a" then
       ' I need var to be a certain type of class
       var1 = new SomeClass()
     elseif which_type = "b" then
       ' I need var1 to be a different type of class
       var1 = new SomeOtherClass()
     end if


  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: var1 can only be one or the other...unless one inherits from the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't... In VB variables must have a specific datatype. [Data Types in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ffsdktda.aspx) says:

> The data type of a programming element refers to what kind of data it can hold and how it stores that data. Data types apply to all values that can be stored in computer memory or participate in the evaluation of an expression.
>
> Every variable [...] has a data type.

To put objects of different classes into one variable:

- they must have a common base class or interface, and
- the variable must be declared using that common class/interface.

Common base

```
  Public Class SomeClass 
      Inherits BaseClassOrInterface
  End Class
  
  Public Class SomeOtherClass 
      Inherits BaseClassOrInterface
  End Class
```

So in your code:

```
  Private var1 as BaseClassOrInterface
```

Now var1 can hold any of (SomeClass, SomeOtherClass, BaseClassOrInterface).

```
  Public Sub New(which_type as string)

      if which_type = "a" then
          var1 = new SomeClass()
      elseif which_type = "b" then
          var1 = new SomeOtherClass()
      end if

  End Sub
```

Alternatively you can declare var1 as [System.Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Object(v=vs.110).aspx), which is the ultimate base class (not recommended though).

```
  Private var1 as Object
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: Why do you not recommend using 'object'?

Comment: Because there's not much you can do with it, except cast it to another datatype - then you get run-time crashes. Using a common base class, any errors will be caught at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

This can only be done if it has a base type like below (C# example)

```
public interface Ibase { }

public class someclass : Ibase {}

public class someotherclass : Ibase {}
```

Then you can say

```
  Private var1 as Ibase

  Public Sub New(which_type as string)

 if which_type = "a" then
   ' I need var to be a certain type of class
   var1 = new SomeClass()
 elseif which_type = "b" then
   ' I need var1 to be a different type of class
   var1 = new SomeOtherClass()
 end if
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("ClassA"))` to instance the  `ClassA` class. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify type restrictions at the class' declaration.

```
Public Class oneClass(Of t As New)

    Private var1 As t

    Public Sub New()
        var1 = New t
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Someclass
    Property Name As String
End Class
```

Then create an instance with:

```
Dim o As New oneClass(Of Someclass)
```

`t As New` restricts to types which have a constructor, because you'll need it when doing `var1 = New t`.
Form more control you could restrict also to an interface that all the classes implement. Using `t As {New, IMyInt}`:

```
Public Class oneClass(Of t As {New, iMyInt})

    Private var1 As t

    Public Sub New()
        var1 = New t
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Someclass
    Implements iMyInt
    Property Name As String
End Class

Public Interface iMyInt
End Interface
```